# Trying to convert a numeric value to css

Tags: javascript, css

I am trying to iterate over a number of DIVS, pull a numeric value from said DIVs, if that value is == to a specific value in the JS, apply a specific CSS Class back to the DIV it came from.

This is the code I have so far

```
const getRating = document.getElementsByClassName('my-ratings');
let getRatingValues = [];
for(var i = 0; i < getRating.length; i++) {
    getRatingValues += getRating[i].textContent;

    if (getRatingValues == 5) {
        getRating.classList.add('rating-5');
    }
    if (getRatingValues == 4) {
        getRating.classList.add('rating-4');
    }
    if (getRatingValues == 3) {
        getRating.classList.add('rating-3');
    }
    if (getRatingValues == 2) {
        getRating.classList.add('rating-2');
    }
    if (getRatingValues == 1) {
        getRating.classList.add('rating-1');
    }
}
```

I feel like I am close, but just can't break the back of it...

At the moment, the script seems to fill the getRatingValues as a string, so if I have values of 5, 3, 1, 2, 2, 4 the getRatingValues will be 531224. Could someone point me in the right direction please?

Comment: `+=` does not add elements to an array. You want `getRatingValues.push(...)`. Once you fix that, things still don't make sense; why is it an array in the first place? What are you trying to do?

Comment: why you define getRatingValues as an array but use it as an integer? thats not clear :) And you can save many space if you write your code dynamical like:

getRating.classList.add('rating-' + getRatingValues);

Comment: `+=` also does something different when the operators are strings (and `textContent` is a string).

Comment: Why are you adding a string to an array?

Comment: I am collecting the values from the DIV with class `my-ratings`, I am then transforming that value into a CSS Class, so if the DIV has text in it that is 3, I generate a css class called ratings-3 and apply it to the DIV

Comment: @epascarello because I am an idiot :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

DRY - and cast to number:

```
let getRatingValues = 0;
document.querySelectorAll('.my-ratings').forEach(function(rate) { // for each my rating
  let val = rate.textContent; // get the rate
  getRatingValues += isNaN(val)?0:+val; // convert to number if is IS a number and add
  rate.classList.add('rating-'+val); // add the class - here or outside the loop?
})
```

I would have thought `getRating.classList.add('rating-'+val);` should be outside the loop since now you will get 5 classes on one div if all 5 are set

For IE you need

```
var ratings = document.querySelectorAll('my-ratings');
for (var i=0;i<ratings.length;i++) {
  let val = ratings[i].innerText, rate = ratings[i];
```

Comment: This is really tidy, but I am getting `document.getElementsByClassName('my-ratings').forEach is not a function`

Comment: Please see update. I changed to use querySelectorAll and IE does not like forEach on nodes - I could have created a working example if I'd had the HTML

Comment: One more thing, getRating is now not defined, do I just create a const and place the document.querySelectorAll in it?

Comment: Ah no. I assume rate.classList.add

Answer (score 1):

You need to convert the string to `Number`.

Change

```
getRatingValues += getRating[i].textContent;
```

to

```
getRatingValues += Number(getRating[i].textContent);
```

Also, your `getRatingValues` should not be initialized to `[]`, instead it should be

```
let getRatingValues = 0;
```

Comment: For completeness, it's probably worth mentioning you can cast the value to a number in a variety of different ways:  `+= Number(var)` or `+= parseInt(var)` or, my favorite, `+= +var`....

Answer (score 0):

Try parseInt

```
getRatingValues += parseInt(getRating[i].textContent);
```

Reference : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt